# Displaying XML in IE

Tags: php, xml, internet-explorer

in a new project, I want to generate an XML file with PHP (I've done this one a lot of times) but now I'm facing a very weird problem, IE doesn't display the XML correctly but in an old project's directory, the XML displays correctly, but in the new project's directory it don't display the XML. The code is:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<root><foo a="b">Tada</foo></root>';
```

In the old project's directory, this program displays:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<root>
    <foo a="b">Tada</foo>
</root>
```

But in the new project's directory it only displays:

```
Tada
```

If I see the source code of the page, in both directories it shows:

```
<root><foo a="b">Tada</foo></root>
```

In Firefox I have no problem. Any idea of what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Marco.

Comment: Try an `application/xml` media type.

Comment: Did you add the XML preamble `<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

Comment: The application/xml does exactly the same as text/xml.

Comment: No, I don't use the preamble, the instruction: header('Content-Type: text/xml'); is supposed to add this part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can be helpul for someone with the same problem:

I'm using PSPad editor to create the PHP files and if in the Options is marked **Ident. bytes in UTF-8 coding** the program generates some characters at the beginning of the file and therefore the XML file is malformed. Thanks to all for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add

```
<?

echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';

?>
```

before you spit out the rest of the xml document!

Comment: You'll need to do some trickery to prevent php from interpreting the `?>` as the end of a php block. `echo '<'.'?xml version="1.0"?'.'>';`

Comment: It doesn't work, the weird part of the problem, is that it works correctly in another directory...

Comment: The stackoverflow does not seem to like it but the php interpreter should see that the '?>' lies within the string. It should be fine.

Comment: Are you the server admin? Perhaps there are some rules applied to the directory you are working within.

Comment: Yes, I'm the administrator and I'm looking for differences between directories...